# can't find RSA Keys list in preferences wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I have compiled code source for wireshark 1.12.8,after installation i don't found RSA Keys list for protocol SSL.

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem building wireshark 2.2.3 from source on CentOS 6.7. It turned out to be because my libgnutls version was too low which caused the wireshark configure to #undef HAVE_LIBGNUTLS.  This causes the RSA key list code to be compiled out.